# Understanding some Galois theoretic identification of a quotient over some 3-adic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}_3$. Let $L=K(\alpha)$ given by $\min_K(\alpha) = x^4-3x^2+18$. This extension is cyclic of degree $4$ with ramification index $2$. In particular, the intertial degree is also $2$. See also [this page](https://www.lmfdb.org/LocalNumberField/3.4.2.2).

Let $L'/L$ be the unique unramified extension of degree $2$. Since $L'/L$ is generated by a primitive $5$-th root of unity $\zeta_5$, it is $L'= K(\alpha,\zeta_5)$.

If I am not wrong, the Galois group of $L'/K$ is
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(L'/K) \simeq C_4 \times C_2 = \langle \sigma' \rangle \times \langle \sigma \rangle.
$$

Suppose that $\sigma: \alpha \mapsto -\alpha, \, \zeta_5 \mapsto \zeta_5$ (which has order $2$) and $\sigma': \alpha \mapsto \alpha, \, \zeta_5 \mapsto \zeta_5^3$ (which has order $4$).

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, it is $Gal(L/K) = Gal(L'/K)/Gal(L'/L)$. A generator of $Gal(L'/L)$ is given by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha, \, \zeta_5 \mapsto \zeta_5^9 = \zeta_5^{-1}$.

If I look at the explicit elements of the quotient, they must be $\{ Id, \bar{\sigma}, \bar{\sigma'}, \bar{\sigma} \bar{\sigma'} \}$ (it is $(\sigma')^2 \in Gal(L'/L)$) **But none of these elements seem to be a generator of the quotient.** (if my computations are correct, all these elements have order $2$ at most). **Since $L/K$ is indeed cyclic, this cannot be possible.**

I assume I made a mistake with identifying my elements. **Could you please say where my line of thought is wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $$L = \Bbb{Q}_3( \zeta_8, \zeta_{16} 3^{1/2}) \qquad \implies \qquad L' =   \Bbb{Q}_3( \zeta_{80}, 3^{1/2})$$
Then it is clear that
$$Gal(L'/\Bbb{Q}_3)=Gal(L'/\Bbb{Q}_3(3^{1/2}))\times Gal(L'/\Bbb{Q}_3(\zeta_{80}))= C_4\times C_2$$
and $Gal(L'/L) = \langle (2,1)\rangle$.

Any element of $Gal(L'/\Bbb{Q}_3)$ whose reduction is the Frobenius will have order $4$ both in $Gal(L'/\Bbb{Q}_3)$ and $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}_3)$

Comment: I am not sure how this has something to do with my question. My question was that I seemed to do a mistake in an argument but cannot see why this is the case.

Comment: Read the last sentence again, any lift of the Frobenius has order 4 in $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}_3)$. The generator of $Gal(L'/L)$ is $(2,1)$ not $(2,0)$.

Comment: How can $(2,1)$ be a generator of $Gal(L'/L)$, assuming you mean the element $\sigma (\sigma')^2$ in my context. It does not fix $\alpha$, so it can't be an element of $Gal(L'/L)$, or am I wrong?

Comment: I meant $0\times C_2$ is sending $3^{1/2}$ to $\pm 3^{1/2}$ and fixing  $\zeta_{80}$.

Comment: Okay, I see. And what is the trick to observe that $L$ and $L'$ has the form as you wrote them down? For me, it looks like it comes out of nowhere.

Comment: In particular, I am really interested where the $3^{1/2}$ appears in $L$ (and how this is related to the original definition $L=\mathbb{Q}_3(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ having minimal polynomial $x^4 - 3x^2 + 18$ over $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

Comment: Sorry for the many questions I suddenly have, but would you mind explaining why there is a $16$-th primitive root of unity in the definition of $L$ as well? Wouldn't it have been enough if we would adjoin $3^{1/2}$ instead of $\zeta_{16} 3^{1/2}$ to $\mathbb{Q}_3$ as well?

Comment: $Gal(\Bbb{Q}_3(\zeta_8,3^{1/3})/\Bbb{Q}_3)= C_2\times C_2$ while $Gal(\Bbb{Q}_3(\zeta_8,3^{1/3}\zeta_{16})/\Bbb{Q}_3)= C_4$ @Rotdat

Comment: Okay, I think I should have better worded my question like this: How do I see that $\mathbb{Q}_3(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}_3(\zeta_8,\zeta_{16} 3^{1/2} )$?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}_3[x]/(x^2-3x+18)=\Bbb{Q}_3[y]/(y^2-y+2)$ unramified of degree $2$ thus $=\Bbb{Q}_3(\zeta_8)$ and $y= -(1+\sqrt{-7})\bmod 3$ has order $8 $ in the residue field thus assuming we chose the root of unity such that $y=\zeta_8\bmod 3$ we get $\Bbb{Q}_3(\alpha)= \Bbb{Q}_3( \sqrt{x})= \Bbb{Q}_3( \sqrt{3y}) =\Bbb{Q}_3( \sqrt{3 \zeta_8})$ by Hensel lemma.